# Getting the class of a Java generic, and interface implementation of generics

Tags: java, generics

I'd like to make a class that looks basically like this:

```
public class MyClass<T implements Serializable) {

   void function() {
      Class c = T.class;
   }
}
```

Two errors:
- I cannot call T.class, even though I can do that with any other object type
- I cannot enforce that T implements Serializable in this way

How do I solve my two generics problems?

Cheers

Nik

Comment: Could you add in an example of what you actually want to achieve?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't get the type.

Generics are implemented using something called [type-erasure](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html).

> When a generic type is instantiated,
>   the compiler translates those types by
>   a technique called type erasure — a
>   process where the compiler removes all
>   information related to type parameters
>   and type arguments within a class or
>   method. Type erasure enables Java
>   applications that use generics to
>   maintain binary compatibility with
>   Java libraries and applications that
>   were created before generics.

The essence of this is that the type information is used by the compiler and discarded, hence not available at runtime.

With regards to the enforcing `T implements Serializable`, you just need the following:

```
public class MyClass<T extends Serializable>)
{
  public void function(T obj) 
  {
    ...
  }
}
```

This is simply referring to the *is a* relationship, so an class that implements `Serializable`, *is a* `Serializable` and can be passed to `function`.

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation, I now understand why it doesn't work, and I've solved my practical problem with the workaround proposed by gjrwebber. Thanks a bunch! :-)

Answer (score 5):

you do this:

```
public class MyClass<T implements Serializable) {

   void function(Class<T> tc) {
      ...
   }
}
```

Basically, you have to pass in the class at run time in order to see it. You could also do something like this:

```
public class MyClass<T implements Serializable) {
   Class<T> ct; 
   public MyClass(Class<T> ct){this.ct = ct;}

   void function() {
       ... //you know what the class is here
   }
}
```

It's kind of annoying, but not really that big of a hassle overall.

Answer (score 3):

Something along these lines should do it.

```
private Class<T> dataType;
Type type = getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
if (type instanceof ParameterizedType) {
    ParameterizedType paramType = (ParameterizedType) type;
    dataType = (Class<T>) paramType.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
} else if (type instanceof Class) {
    dataType = (Class<T>) type;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the workaround, that helped me solve the problem, and the other answers helped me understand the problem. :-) You guys are the best! :-)

Comment: I got a sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.TypeVariableImpl cannot be cast to java.lang.Class, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do T.class because java does not actually know which class T is at runtime.

All that information is lost at compilation.

To get the class object for T you can either call getClass() on an instance of T (if you have access to one) or require the user to pass the class object as an argument to `function`, like:

```
void function(Class<T> c)
```

Comment: The syntax for generic argument bounding is <T extends Serializable> not <T implements Serializable>

Comment: Thanks for the quick feedback. (1) The problem with that is that in my generic function I want to use functions that take T.class as an input parameter. If I cannot do it this way, a not so good workaround would be to instantiate an object of class T, but as I understand it I cannot say "new T()" either, again because of type-erasure?
(2) Doh, didn't see the typo. But, my Java compiler claims it expects a comma where I write implements, that's what I meant by it. EDIT: Thanks tkopec, extends worked much better, I didn't know I could extend an interface

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible without tricks.
The  [Java Generics FAQ](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TypeParameters.html#FAQ201) provides an idea for a workaround.